# Tool or tricks to analyze offline Java heap dumps (.hprof)

Tags: java, visualvm, heap-dump

Are there any tools that allow offline analysis (including summary/sorting/sifting) of an .hprof file?  Or can you run VisualVM, hat etc in batch mode?

I'm interested in something that can take an input .hprof file, crunch it and generate reports.

I assume you would need to pass in a bunch of options to configure the report, so if you know any helpful tips, please weigh in.

Preferably scriptable so I could run a bunch at once.

Comment: By "offline" do you mean "headless"?  I think of "offline" as meaning "outside the context of the running JVM instance".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) does everything you need.

Comment: can you add command line switches to say "crunch this .hprof offline"?

Comment: Look for ParseHeapDump.sh (.bat on Windows) in this FAQ: http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ

Answer (score 14):

You can use [jhat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jhat.html)  to parse/navigate the memory dump of an `.hprof` file.

```
$ jhat heapdump.hprof
Reading from heapdump.hprof...

Started HTTP server on port 7000
Server is ready.
```

The tool comes with the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use jmap -histo ? What sort of report are you looking to extract?

Comment: jmap -histo does not work against a .hprof file ; it expects a pid

Comment: Basically anything that would help identify memory leaks.  Offhand I'd say 'biggest objects' --both shallow and deep.

Answer (score 2):

hard to beat [yourkit java profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/).  It costs money, but it is worth every penny.

Comment: but can you run heap dump analysis "in batch", i.e. via a script to generate the reports rather than waiting...waiting..waiting...while it loads and churns...?

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you use IntelliJ IDEA, you can open *.hprof memory snapshots, too: Run | Open Profiler Snapshot | Open

Official documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyze-hprof-memory-snapshots.html

Answer (score 0):

Es MAT (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)  is the way to go. Check http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/search/label/memory, especially http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2009/07/eclipse-memory-analyzer-10-useful.html

Answer (score 0):

JDK6 comes with jhat which parses and creates an html report.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html